# How to pass a nullable type to a P/invoked function

Tags: c#, .net, interop, pinvoke, optional-parameters

I have a few p/invoked functions (but I'm rewriting my code at the moment so I'm tidying up) and I want to know how to use/pass a nullable type as one of the parameters. working with int types isn't a problem but given the following:

```
[DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref Guid ClassGuid, int? enumerator, IntPtr hwndParent, uint Flags);
```

I'd like to be able to pass the `Guid` parameter as a nullable type. As it stands at the moment I can call it as:

```
SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref tGuid, null, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)SetupDiFlags.DIGCF_PRESENT );
```

but I need the first parameter to also be passable as `null`.

Comment: @River Mine is not the offending question as this was asked way back in 2009 ;)

Comment: the new one is an attempt to create a canonical version of this problem, with more solutions that are more general.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible to pass a Nullable type into a PInvoke'd function without some ... interesting byte manipulation in native code that is almost certainly not what you want.

If you need the ability to pass a struct value as NULL to native code declare an overload of your PInvoke declaration which takes an IntPtr in the place of the struct and pass IntPtr.Zero

```
[DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref Guid ClassGuid, ref int enumerator, IntPtr hwndParent, uint Flags);
[DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref Guid ClassGuid, IntPtr enumerator, IntPtr hwndParent, uint Flags);
```

Note: I added a ref class to the first signature.  If the native signature can take NULL, it is likely a pointer type.  Hence you must pass value types by reference.

Now you can make calls like the following

```
if (enumerator.HasValue) { 
  SetupDiGetClassDevs(someGuid, ref enumerator.Value, hwnd, flags);
} else {
  SetupDiGetClassDevs(someGuid, IntPtr.Zero, hwnd, flags);
}
```

Comment: I have been overloading my P/invoke functions thus far. My question was to see if I could shortcut this and tidy up my code some more by not needing to overload. So far I have been able to pass off int (parameter 2) as a nullable value with no problems does this mean this restrition only applies to structured types?
Another thing in one incarnation of my code I defined parameter 2 as `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string Enumerator` which also allows me to nullify this parameter during use.

Comment: My apologies... I can't get away with a nullable int :)