# How do I assign a null value to a struct for a pinvoke call?

Tags: c#, struct, pinvoke, marshalling

I would like to call [`LsaOpenPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/aa378299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which takes a [`LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct. I am using [the struct definition from pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES.html). This struct has the field `public LSA_UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;`.

The `LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` MSDN article says:

> When you call `LsaOpenPolicy`, initialize the members of this structure to **NULL** or zero because the function does not use the information.

And specifically:

> **ObjectName**
>
> Should be **NULL**.

While I can assign the other fields of the `LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` struct to `IntPtr.Zero` (or just plain `0` for the value types), I cannot see a way to do so for `ObjectName`. Specifically,

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IntPtr' to 'LSA_UNICODE_STRING'

What should I do in this case? Should I just initialise a `LSA_UNICODE_STRING` of length zero (length 0, maximumlength 0, empty/null buffer)? Should I change the `LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` definition so that field is an `IntPtr`? Should I make it nullable and assign `null` to that field?

I have very little experience with memory management, so I am rather wary of anything that could cause memory leaks.

Comment: It might not be the prettiest sollution, but what happens when you cast to an object before you pass the argument?

Comment: @Jordy `(LSA_UNICODE_STRING)(object)IntPtr.Zero` compiles, but throws a `InvalidCastException` at runtime. Both methods I suggested at the end of my question work as far as I can tell, but I have no idea if I will run into any problems down the line.

Comment: Pinvoke is a tricky thing... If it works as you would expect you may count yourself lucky. Basic rule of thumb with Pinvoke: If it works, don't touch it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare `LSA_UNICODE_STRING` to be a `class` rather than a `struct`. By doing so you make it a reference type. That matches the declaration of `LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` because `ObjectName` has type `PLSA_UNICODE_STRING` which is a pointer to the struct. You do need to specify `LayoutKind.Sequential` when you do this since that's not the default for a class. Once you've made this change, you can set the variable to `null`.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class PLSA_UNICODE_STRING 
{
    public UInt16 Length;
    public UInt16 MaximumLength;
    public IntPtr Buffer;
}
```

You can adopt the same policy for `LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` to allow that to be passed as `null`.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
class PLSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES
{
   public uint Length;
   public IntPtr RootDirectory;
   public PLSA_UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
   public uint Attributes;
   public IntPtr SecurityDescriptor;
   public IntPtr SecurityQualityOfService;
}

[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
static extern uint LsaOpenPolicy(
    PLSA_UNICODE_STRING SystemName,
    PLSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
    uint DesiredAccess,
    out IntPtr PolicyHandle
);
```

Note that the declaration on pinvoke.net erroneously uses `SetLastError=true` on `LsaOpenPolicy`. That's wrong because the error code comes back in the return value. I also removed the setting of `PreserveSig` to `true` since that is the default. Their declaration of `LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` also appears wrong since the `ObjectName` parameter has type `LSA_UNICODE_STRING` which is the struct rather than a pointer to it.

I would advise you to treat what you find on pinvoke.net with extreme scepticism. A large proportion of the declarations on that site are simply incorrect.

You ask about the possibility of using nullable types. According to @JaredPar's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049623/how-to-pass-a-nullable-type-to-a-p-invoked-function#1049660), that's not an option.

Comment: OK, I re-worked my answer to match what I think you are asking. Sorry for the misunderstanding first time round.

Comment: I actually have a field (`LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] UserRights`) elsewhere (`LsaAddAccountRights`), which does not work with a class (I'm guessing I would have needed to do some marshalling). Declaring both a struct and a class (giving the class the name `PLSA...`, which is fitting anyway), works. Thanks! Also, thank you for digging up the information on nullable types - I forgot they had a different layout in memory. Just out of curiosity, what do you think of declaring `ObjectName` to be of the type `IntPtr`? Would that break anything?

Comment: That would also be just fine. If you actually wanted to pass a non-null value then you'd have some more work to do. You'd need to marshal struct to pointer, which involves allocation of unmanaged memory. A bit more boilerplate. If you always pass `null` then `IntPtr` is fine.