# Any alternative about CS0233 for sizeof(T) in StructLayoutAttribute?

Tags: c#, generics, struct, marshalling

Wrote the following struct to minimize the number of types for vectors with different components:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, Size = 3 * sizeof(T))]
public struct Vector3<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    public T X, Y, Z;

    public Vector3(T x, T y, T z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

This is basically, to avoid writing numerous types such `Vec3u8u8u8`, `Vec4i32i32i32` and so on.

Also because of the need to enforce the type, e.g. sometimes `byte` instead of `int`.

However, the above code won't compile because of `sizeof(T)`, producing [CS0233](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0233):

> 'identifier' does not have a predefined size, therefore sizeof can only be used in an unsafe context

In case you ask, these types won't be marshalled back and forth with unmanaged side.

But I will occasionally need to use `Unsafe.SizeOf<T>` or `Marshal.SizeOf<T>` on them.

**Question:**

Can you suggest a working alternative?

Comment: Isn't [`Size`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.size?view=net-7.0) optional? From the docs: *This field must be equal or greater than the total size, in bytes, of the members of the class or structure.   This field is primarily for compiler writers who want to extend the memory occupied by a structure for direct, unmanaged access.*  If I just don't set `Pack` then `Unsafe.SizeOf<>` works just fine, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/InJjaL.

Comment: Now `Marshal.SizeOf<Vector3<int>>()` fails, but that seems to be because it simply doesn't support generics, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/mUwToY.

Comment: You can see the restriction that `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()` does not support generics in the reference source here: [Marshal.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4af855b0101bad16a4e25a7ec3c4c6a2f2984fb0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/Marshal.cs#L125); it throws whenever `t.IsGenericType`.  You won't be able to use your `Vector3<T>` with `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()` whether or not you set `Pack`.

Comment: Okay, fair enough, I abandon this route, thank you!

Comment: Should I make that an answer?

Comment: Yes, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`StructLayoutAttribute.Size`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.size?view=net-7.0) is optional.**  If you don't set it, .NET will compute the size automatically.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.size?view=net-7.0):

> This field must be equal or greater than the total size, in bytes, of the members of the class or structure. **This field is primarily for compiler writers who want to extend the memory occupied by a structure for direct, unmanaged access.**

If I simply remove it from `Vector3<T>` like so:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Vector3<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    public T X, Y, Z;
    public Vector3(T x, T y, T z) => (X, Y, Z) = (x, y, z);
}
```

Then `Unsafe.SizeOf<Vector3<T>()` will work for any valid `T` such as `int` or `double`:

```
Console.WriteLine(Unsafe.SizeOf<Vector3<int>>()); // 12
Console.WriteLine(Unsafe.SizeOf<Vector3<double>>()); // 24
```

Demo #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/InJjaL).

However, **[`Marshal.SizeOf<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?view=net-7.0#system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-sizeof(system-type)) simply does not support generics**. (See demo #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mUwToY)). The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?view=net-7.0#system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-sizeof(system-type)) are a little ambiguous about this.  For `Marshal.Sizeof(Type t)` the docs remark:

> **Exceptions**
> `ArgumentException`
> The t parameter is a generic type definition.

While there is no similar remark for `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()`, a check of the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4af855b0101bad16a4e25a7ec3c4c6a2f2984fb0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/Marshal.cs#L125) shows that the method throws whenever `typeof(T)` is generic.

So, what are your options?

**Firstly**, you could replace all uses of `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()` with `Unsafe.SizeOf<T>()` in your codebase, and continue using your `Vector3<T>` struct.

**Secondly**, if you must continue to use `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()`, you may need to create non-generic types like `Vector3Double` and `Vector3Int` for every required component type.  However, you could reduce duplicated code by extracting an interface that defines a minimal set of operations for vectors, then extract any additional required code into helper methods.  .NET 7's [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math) makes this fairly straightforward.

First define an vector interface with some minimal required operations like so:

```
public interface IVector3<TVector, TValue> : IAdditionOperators<TVector, TVector, TVector>, IAdditiveIdentity<TVector, TVector>, IMultiplyOperators<TVector, TValue, TVector>
    where TValue : unmanaged, INumber<TValue>
    where TVector : IVector3<TVector, TValue>, new ()
{
    TValue X { get; init; }
    TValue Y { get; init; }
    TValue Z { get; init; }
}
```

Next, implement for your required component value types e.g.:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Vector3Double :  IVector3<Vector3Double, double>
{
    public double X { get; init; }
    public double Y { get; init; }
    public double Z { get; init; }

    public Vector3Double(double x, double y, double z) => (X, Y, Z) = (x, y, z);

    public static Vector3Double operator +(Vector3Double left, Vector3Double right) => new(left.X + right.X, left.Y + right.Y, left.Z + right.Z);
    public static Vector3Double operator checked +(Vector3Double left, Vector3Double right) => checked(new(left.X + right.X, left.Y + right.Y, left.Z + right.Z));
    public static Vector3Double operator *(Vector3Double left, double right) => new(right * left.X, right * left.Y, right * left.Z);
    public static Vector3Double operator checked *(Vector3Double left, double right) => checked(new(right * left.X, right * left.Y, right * left.Z));
    public static Vector3Double AdditiveIdentity => new Vector3Double();
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Vector3Int :  IVector3<Vector3Int, int>
{
    public int X { get; init; }
    public int Y { get; init; }
    public int Z { get; init; }

    public Vector3Int(int x, int y, int z) => (X, Y, Z) = (x, y, z);

    public static Vector3Int operator +(Vector3Int left, Vector3Int right) => new(left.X + right.X, left.Y + right.Y, left.Z + right.Z);
    public static Vector3Int operator checked +(Vector3Int left, Vector3Int right) => checked(new(left.X + right.X, left.Y + right.Y, left.Z + right.Z));
    public static Vector3Int operator *(Vector3Int left, int right) =>  new(right * left.X, right * left.Y, right * left.Z);
    public static Vector3Int operator checked *(Vector3Int left, int right) => checked(new(right * left.X, right * left.Y, right * left.Z));
    public static Vector3Int AdditiveIdentity => new Vector3Int();
}
```

And now you will be able to create extension methods base on these interfaces, for instance:

```
public static class VectorExtensions
{
    public static TValue Dot<TVector, TValue>(this TVector left, TVector right) where TValue : unmanaged, INumber<TValue> where TVector : IVector3<TVector, TValue>, new ()
        => left.X + right.X + left.Y + right.Y + left.Z + right.Z;
    
    public static TVector Sum<TVector, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TVector> vectors) where TValue : unmanaged, INumber<TValue> where TVector : IVector3<TVector, TValue>, new ()
        => vectors.Aggregate(TVector.AdditiveIdentity, (s, c) => s + c);

    public static TVector Lerp<TVector, TValue>(TVector a, TVector b, TValue t) where TValue : unmanaged, INumber<TValue> where TVector : IVector3<TVector, TValue>, new ()
        => a * (TValue.MultiplicativeIdentity - t) + b*t;
}
```

With that done, you can do things like:

```
var vec1 = new Vector3Double(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
var vec2 = new Vector3Double(2.2, 2.2, 2.2);

var sum = vec1 + vec2;
var scaled = vec1 * 2.2;
var dotP = vec1.Dot<Vector3Double, double>(vec2);
var aggregate = new [] { vec1, vec2 }.Sum<Vector3Double, double>();
```

Notes:

- I was unable to get type inferencing to work automatically for the `VectorExtensions` methods, which is why I had to specify the generic parameters explicitly.
- Your vector type is a `struct`, and Microsoft recommends that structs be [immutable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct).  So, in my `IVector3` interface, I made `X`, `Y` and `Z` be init-only.

Demo #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LVbX6M).

**Thirdly**, In [Inconsistent behavior of `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()` and `Marshal.SizeOf<T>(T structure)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77661100/3744182), [Jeppe Stig Nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336654/jeppe-stig-nielsen) points out that the [`Marshal.SizeOf<T> (T structure)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?view=net-8.0#system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-sizeof-1(-0)) overload actually does support generics.  Thus, it seems you can do:

```
var size = Marshal.SizeOf<Vector3<int>>(default); // 12
```

And it will return 12 instead of throwing.

That being said, experimentation shows that if the generic type `T` is a nullable value type, the above will throw with an `ArgumentNullException`, e.g.:

```
var size = Marshal.SizeOf<Nullable<int>>(default); // Throws ArgumentNullException
```

In such a case you will need to pass in a default instance of the underlying non-nullable type, e.g.:

```
var size = Marshal.SizeOf<Nullable<int>>(default(int)); // 4
```

Interestingly enough, for nullable value types the size returned seems to be the size of the underlying non-nullable value type not including the size of the nullable wrapper.  This may be explained by the fact that the method is documented to return:

> The size, in bytes, of the specified object in **unmanaged code**.

So it would seem that nullable types may not be supported for automatic marshalling, or are marshalled as their underlying valuetype.

Notes:

- Even if you can compute the unmanaged size of a generic struct, you can't actually P/Invoke a generic.  See:

  1. [Why are generics not supported with PInvoke #46204](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/46204)
  2. [Marshal.SizeOf(Type) is throwing incorrectly on generic types #46426](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46426).
  3. [How to pass a nullable type to a P/invoked function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1049623).

.NET Core demo #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tOMngB) and .NET Framework demo #5 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sjQS3b).

Comment: Even though I cannot use .NET 7 because I'm under Unity, I accept your answer because it's definitely right!

Comment: @aybe - answer updated.