# Inconsitent behavior of `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()` and `Marshal.SizeOf<T>(T structure)`

Tags: c#, .net-core, size, marshalling, sizeof

I see inconsistent behavior of the [`Marshal.SizeOf<>` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof) overloads. For brevity, I will consider here only the generic overloads.

This was tried with the .NET 8 runtime.

**ISSUE 1: `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()` allows too little**

Consider this code:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

    int size1a = Marshal.SizeOf<KeyValuePair<int, int>>(KeyValuePair.Create(123, 456));  // good, gives 8
    int size1b = Marshal.SizeOf<KeyValuePair<int, int>>(default);                        // good, gives 8
    int size2 = Marshal.SizeOf<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();                                // throws?!?
```

Explanation: `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` is a `struct` which holds two nonstatic fields of type `TKey` and `TValue`, respectively. When I construct it with `int` (`struct` without managed fields) on both positions `TKey` and `TValue`, I have a type `KeyValuePair<int, int>` which holds no reference type members and is therefore "unmanaged".

Expected: `size2` can be determined (as `8`) just as `size1a` and `size1b`

Actual: blows up with an `ArgumentException` saying that `T` cannot be a generic type

Question: Is it not entirely inconsistent that the size cannot be found, when it is found with no issue by the overload taking an arg `structure`?

Note that the closed type `KeyValuePair<int, int>` will happily satisfy the generic constraint `where TSomething : unmanaged` which exists since C# 7.3 (from 2018). This also makes it natural to expect that its size can be determined.

**ISSUE 2: `Marshal.SizeOf<T>(T structure)` allows too much!**

Let us put in manged types in `KeyValuePair<,>`:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...

    int size3 = Marshal.SizeOf<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(KeyValuePair.Create("arbitrarily long text", "can go in here"));
```

Expected: Call should lead to an exception since the type/instance holds references to managed objects (in this example of type `System.String` (class)).

Actual: Call succeeds, and returns a value that depends on build platform. For example, `size3` becomes `8` (`== 4+4`) when built for **x86** and becomes `16` (`== 8+8`) when built for **x64**, and so on.

Question: Why? I am seeing twice the width of the runtime's references.

This works correctly on .NET Framework 4.8. Here, attempting to find `size3` (must use `new KeyValuePair<string, string>(...)` explicitly since static `Create` method is absent) leads to:

> ArgumentException: Type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.

So *ISSUE 2* must be new somehow on .NET Core. As I said, I am using .NET 8.

---

Should I report this as bugs in .NET, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46426) any relevant?

Comment: Related: [Any alternative about CS0233 for sizeof(T) in StructLayoutAttribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75495331/3744182).   Can you use `Unsafe.SizeOf<T>()` instead?

Comment: Generic structs are not applicable for PInvoke so `Marshal.SizeOf` is not relevant. What are you *actually* trying to do that you need the size of such a struct?

Comment: The code for `Marshal.SizeOf()` and `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()` throw for generic type parameters https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/4af855b0101bad16a4e25a7ec3c4c6a2f2984fb0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Runtime/InteropServices/Marshal.cs#L125 but `Marshal.SizeOf(Object)` and `Marshal.SizeOf<T>(T)` do not. Why that is, I don't know: neither are supposed to work.

Comment: @Charlieface, Is it even clear what they "are supposed" to do? Part of the point of the comment by Matteo Umili is that there is a difference between `.IsGenericType` and e.g. `.ContainsGenericParameters`.

Comment: Well you can't actually marshal `KeyValuePair` whatever you do because it's generic, so it's a moot point whether you can find its marshalling size. Why would you be calling it in the first place?

Comment: @Charlieface, Not sure what it means, I cannot marshal it. Something like [this example](https://tio.run/##jY9BawJBDIXv8ytyKrvaXayttrLqxYMHWxAUPcdsKoHZGdjMClL87euUFfRS6CW8vPeFJKQZKbVto@KOsDlr4Kowj12@8NYyBfFO8yU7roUKYzRgEAKyqApr82MAblbjFL8ZTl5K@EJxSRqz3xygZJIKLSDM4GX4@jYav39MBlHldxnXP6A9OET2CTtzxecd2obXKPVUXHiGWOY9oMgkf4TpoZtdxPu95XxfS@BPcZxQNt/6Tajjr0madhT1@//HL@bStlc) compiles and runs with no issue? At the `c++` statement, the size of the pointer seems relevant.

Comment: That's not PInvoke marshalling, that's unsafe code, something entirely different. PInvoke is when you use `DllImport` to call out to a C/C++ library etc, unsafe code is when you do pointer manipulation inside C# directly. For that you should be using the `sizeof` operator (which computes the size *on the C# side*) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/sizeof note the comment in the docs: "The result of the sizeof operator might differ from the result of the Marshal.SizeOf method, which returns the size of a type in unmanaged memory."

Comment: Marshal.SizeOf is really for interop scenarios where generics aren't supposed to play well anyway. Issue #1 may be ... lazily "by design" https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46426 however on issue #2, if there's a difference between .NET 4.8 and .NET Core this is maybe a case where Microsoft is still listening if I understand their logic a bit.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatives:

For Issue 1: When dealing with unmanaged types, you can explicitly specify the type when calling Marshal.SizeOf. For example, instead of Marshal.SizeOf<KeyValuePair<int, int>>(), you can do the following:

```
int size2 = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(KeyValuePair<int, int>));
```

This way, you explicitly provide the type information, and it should work without throwing an exception.

For Issue 2: You can avoid the issue by not using KeyValuePair with reference types when you need to calculate the size. Instead, you can create a custom struct to represent the data you want to work with, ensuring it contains only value types (not reference types). For example:

```
public struct MyKeyValuePair
{
    public string Key;
    public string Value;
}
```

Then, you can calculate the size of this custom struct without encountering issues related to reference types:

```
int size3 = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyKeyValuePair));
By using a custom struct that only contains value types, you avoid the problem of Marshal.SizeOf incorrectly calculating the size based on reference types.
```

Keep in mind that these workarounds may require refactoring your code, especially in the case of Issue 2, where you'd need to replace usages of KeyValuePair with your custom struct. These workarounds address the limitations of the Marshal.SizeOf method in .NET Core/.NET 5+ for the specific scenarios you've described.

Comment: What you write on Issue 1 does not work on the runtimes I tried it on. Did you even try it? What you write on Issue 2, I do not get. You say I can avoid the bug by not calling the method with the input that reveals the bug, and you say a nongeneric struct with `string` members contains only value types? We can agree `string` is a reference type (that was the entire point with my question)?